# Why is my 4D Write document not saving with the rest of record?

Tags: 4d-database

In 4D, how do you guarantee that a 4D Write document is saved with the rest of the record?

Answer (score 2):

I know, I'm late. If you want to save your 4D Write automatically, then create a field in the table you are modifying with an underscore as last character.

Your 4D Write area name: myLetter
Your table field name: myLetter_    <-- the 'underscore' is the secret

And as soon as you hit ACCEPT, 4D will save it together with the record.

If you are using SAVE RECORD, that's the hard work. In the line before the SAVE RECORD you need to transfer the 4D Write Area into your field:

[TableName]myLetter_:=WR AREA TO BLOB(myLetter)
Save Record([TableName])

Peter

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between ACCEPT and SAVE RECORD ([table]).

When saving a 4D Write document on an input form, you need to use ACCEPT.

Comment: If I remember correctly, SAVE RECORD saves the record. ACCEPT will attempt to save the record and close the input window.